# Prove that the modules of each eigenvalue​ of a unitary matrix is unity.

Tags: linear-algebra

I can't get answer of this question so give right answer

Comment: Welcome to MSE. What did you try?

Comment: Use the fact that $det(A^\theta)$ is equal to  $\overline{det(A)}$

Answer (score 1):

Hint: $U$ unitary means $\|U v\| = \|v\|$ for every vector $v$. Now consider $v$ an eigenvector.

Answer (score 0):

The unitary matrices form a group, and also form a bounded set. If
a unitary matrix $U$ had an eigenvalue $\lambda$ with $|\lambda|>1$
then the sequence $(U^n)$ is unbounded - contradiction. If
it has an eigenvalue smaller than one, consider $U^{-1}$ instead.